# Debugging Web Service by mocking a client in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have not used VB.Net my entire life but I need to create a piece of code in the language for testing purposes.

We provide a web service to various clients who build applications in their desired languages but post data in XML format to the service. One of the clients keeps getting wrong values and insists the problem is on our end so I want to simulate the XML posts to prove there is a problem with their implementation which is in VB.Net.

I have googled a piece of code and set it up on Visual Studio 2015 but cannot get it to run.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
......
......    

        Dim myxml As String
        myxml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
        myxml += "<ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest xmlns='AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'>"
        myxml += "<merchantAuthentication>"
        myxml += "<name>xxx</name>"
        myxml += "<transactionKey>yyy</transactionKey>"
        myxml += "</merchantAuthentication>"
        myxml += "<refId>Sample</refId>"
        myxml += "<subscription>"
        myxml += "<name>Sample subscription</name>"
        myxml += "<paymentSchedule>"
        myxml += "<interval>"
        myxml += "<length>1</length>"
        myxml += "<unit>months</unit>"
        myxml += "</interval>"
        myxml += "<startDate>2010-03-15</startDate>"
        myxml += "<totalOccurrences>12</totalOccurrences>"
        myxml += "<trialOccurrences>1</trialOccurrences>"
        myxml += "</paymentSchedule>"
        myxml += "<amount>10.29</amount>"
        myxml += "<trialAmount>0.00</trialAmount>"
        myxml += "<payment>"
        myxml += "<creditCard>"
        myxml += "<cardNumber>4111111111111111</cardNumber>"
        myxml += "<expirationDate>2010-08</expirationDate>"
        myxml += "</creditCard>"
        myxml += "</payment>"
        myxml += "<billTo>"
        myxml += "<firstName>John</firstName>"
        myxml += "<lastName>Smith</lastName>"
        myxml += "</billTo>"
        myxml += "</subscription>"
        myxml += "</ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest>"


        Try
            Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myxml)
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api"), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
            request.ContentType = "text/xml"
            Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            End Using
            Dim ReceiveStream As Stream
            Dim encode As Encoding
            Dim sr As StreamReader
            Using myresponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                If Response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                    Dim message As String = [String].Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", Response.StatusCode)
                    Throw New ApplicationException(message)
                End If
                ReceiveStream = myresponse.GetResponseStream()
                encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
                sr = New StreamReader(ReceiveStream)
                Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd)
            End Using






        Catch Exc As Exception


        Finally


        End Try

    End Sub
```

I cannot compile the code to run because Visual Studio points out the following issues:

- 'ContentLength' is not a member of 'HttpWebRequest'
- 'GetRequestStream' is not a member of 'HttpWebRequest'
- 'GetResponse' is not a member of 'HttpWebRequest'
- 'Response' is not declared, can see this but don't know what namespace it belongs to

Any help with this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Either the code you found is for ASP.NET, or you could try replacing `Response` with `myresponse`.

Comment: As for the other errors, try making sure you target a full version of the .NET Framework. Right-click your project and go to `Properties > Compile > Advanced Compile Options`. In the `Target Framework` menu make sure you target a Framework which's name **does not** contain `Client Profile`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can't find Target Framework in Visual Studio 2015 Edition

Comment: Is it perhaps in the `Properties > Application` tab?

Comment: You're right, It's an ASP.NET code. Created new project and appears to be no errors

Comment: You can't use "POST" in a request in Net Library.  The POST has to be part of a response.

Comment: Would you be able to do same thing on VB.NET? I mean the piece of code in VB.NET?

Comment: This is a lot of effort and the wrong way to go about debugging an issue with web services. Your implementation will have the option of logging the incoming requests. You could just ask the client to provide the request XML as well. Do one of those to get the request and send it to your service using soapUI (free tool your Web Service developers should already have). The response you get in soapUI can be reviewed to see if it meets expectations for the given request. You can't go writing code in a language you don't know every time someone questions your response XML.

Comment: For me to get here you know the situation is very frustrating. I printed the posted XML which coming blank and couldn't understand why. That's why I needed to know whether it's VB thing or the way he's structured his code. If I got a working implementation then I'd give the developer to use. Anyway, I managed to sort the issue